# Repeat a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume this very simple SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE time < '2010-01-01'
```

Now, how can I assemble a query where the time part is actually an 'array'?

Somehow between the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE time < ['2010-01-01', '2012-01-01']
```

The Select should be executed two times but result in a single result set.

Note, that this sample array contains only two items, but it may contain many more, as the results are actually coming from a sub-query.

Postgresql 9.3

Comment: Please show some sample data and the expected output  based on that (edit your question)

Comment: The actual query is MUCH more complicated and involves GROUP BY, counting items over time, so I am interested on a running calculation over time.

Comment: @JohnDoe: You are asking for details in a chosen path to a solution, but I doubt its the best approach. Present the *problem*, not fragments of a would-be solution. Back it up with a table definition, sample data and an expected result. Exact data types are crucial here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ANY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-subquery.html#AEN13976) works for this, e.g:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE time < ANY (SELECT '2010-01-01' UNION ALL SELECT '2012-01-01')
```

Comment: Looks good to me: select id
from (values(1),(2), (3)) as t(id)
where id <= any (array[1,2])

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have given a bad sample SQL because `SELECT * FROM a WHERE time < '2012-01-01'` will give you all the dates including `'2010-01-01'`

If you are just wanting to combine two identically structured reultsets into one then `UNION` operator will help you here:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE time < '2010-01-01'
UNION
SELECT * FROM a WHERE time < '2012-01-01'
```

If you wanted to include the results of `< '2010-01-01'` from both queries you would need to use the `UNION ALL`

Comment: Yes, but the point is I do not know how many entries will be in this array, the results are coming from another select, so the UNION will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick - use `ANY` as in:

```
select *
from a
where time < any(array['2010-01-01'::timestamp, '2012-01-01'::timestamp])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say that Time is coming from subquery, you can include that subquery into Non Equi join (<):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM Table_1 AS A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Time FROM DATE_Array_Table) AS B
       on (A.Time < B.Time)
```

There is INNER JOIN on table with array of dates, in this case of course you will get duplicates, but querying only table A with Distinct values will solve that easily.

In this case it does not matter how many Time value you will have (1,2,3,4, ...). You have wrote that your final query is with aggregation, so be aware of duplication in my solution.